# Why won't `import` correctly capture the inside of a window rendered in OpenGL, while `scrot` will?

Tags: opengl, screenshot, imagemagick

I have been experimenting with OpenGL recently, and I decided to take a screenshot of one of my fancy triangles with `import`, which is part of `imagemagick`.  However, on two different computers, one running LXDE on an Intel processor with integrated graphics and the other using stock Ubuntu on an AMD Fusion processor, and the result was the same: `scrot` perfectly captures my entire screen, whereas `import` has problems with my OpenGL window but nothing else (by "problems", I either mean data from other windows showing up in the image, or the image showing the window as not displaying anything at all).

What is causing this?  Why does `scrot` work perfectly fine with OpenGL, while `import` doesn't?